# Maven site on aggregator POM

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-site-plugin, parent-pom

I have an aggregator POM and want to create a site for the aggregator POM and the containing modules.

I have configured the following, on the aggregator pom

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>mysite.com</id>
        <url>file:///Users/myUser/Sites/local/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

The issue is that every time I run `mvn site site:stage` the links of the modules are broken. The only working solution I have found is to set the aggregator POM as a parent on the modules.
i.e

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

On every module

But this is not an option as I want to have the modules as stand-alone, just want to build the report for all of them.

Is there a way to create the site without any modification on the modules? Only modifying the aggregator POM

Comment: Is it that you don't want to change the modules at all - or that you don't want to establish the parent/child relationship between the aggregator and the modules?

Comment: I want to see if this can be done without changing the modules at all.
I already found a way to make it work without establishing the parent/child relationship, but it also implies changes on the modules.

Comment: There is no way that I know of to do it with no changes.